# Column overlapping on first page load only

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, overlapping

Hi I am using Bootstrap 4, I am working on a project here http://eatout.sanaalitech.com/products.php I am facing a very strange problem.I am using bootstrap grid and my columns overlaps on the first page load only on mobile view,on desktop it works fine, when I refresh the page it works fine on the mobile as well. 
I have tried the following but still not working
 1) .col-lg-3{ display:block; position:relative;}
2) I have tried enclosing every 4 products in a row instead of taking all of them in a single row like this

content here
    content here
    content here
    content here





    content here
    content here
    content here
    content here





    content here
    content here
    content here
    content here

3) I have also completely deleted this and made it again with cards but they also overlap on the first load only on mobile view.

Problem appears on the first load only.

I have added image on first page load .[image]

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:5em;">
     <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-lg-12" >
            <ul class="filter-tabs text-center">
                <li data-filter=".maincourse"><a href="#!" >Main Courses</a></li>
                <li data-filter=".desserts"><a href="#!" id="desserts">Desserts</a></li>
                <li class="active" data-filter="*"><a href="#!">View All</a></li>
                <li data-filter=".starters"><a href="#!">Starters</a></li>
                <li data-filter=".extras"><a href="#!">Extras</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="projects">
                <div class="row">


                        <div class="col-lg-3 item maincourse mb-3" >
                            <div class="product ">
                                <img src="Images/banner-image4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                <div class="text-center mb-3 mt-3">
                                    <h4>Meal Platter</h4>
                                    <h7>£8.99</h7>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-3  item desserts mb-3" >
                            <div class="product ">
                                <img src="Images/dessert.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                <div class="text-center mb-3 mt-3">
                                    <h4>Meal Platter</h4>
                                    <h7>£8.99</h7>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                            <div class="col-lg-3 item maincourse mb-3">
                                <div class="product ">
                                        <img src="Images/main-meal-5.jpg" class="img-fluid img-filter">
                                        <div class="text-center mb-3 mt-3">
                                            <h4>Meal Platter</h4>
                                            <h7>£8.99</h7>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-lg-3  item starters mb-3">
                                <div class="product ">
                                    <img src="Images/banner-image3.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                    <div class="text-center mb-3 mt-3">
                                        <h4>Meal Platter</h4>
                                        <h7>£8.99</h7>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="col-lg-3 item maincourse mb-3">
                                <div class="product ">
                                    <img src="Images/main-meal-2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                    <div class="text-center mb-3 mt-3">
                                        <h4>Roll Platter</h4>
                                        <h7>£8.99</h7>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-3 item starters mb-3">
                                <div class="product ">
                                    <img src="Images/main-meal-4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                    <div class="text-center mb-3 mt-3">
                                        <h4>Vege Starter</h4>
                                        <h7>£7.99</h7>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-3 item desserts mb-3">
                                <div class="product ">
                                    <img src="Images/dessert-2.jpg" class="img-fluid img-filter">
                                    <div class="text-center mb-3 mt-3">
                                        <h4>Rasberry cake</h4>
                                        <h7>£4.99</h7>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 item maincourse mb-3">
                                <div class="product ">
                                        <img src="Images/main-meal-3.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                        <div class="text-center mb-3 mt-3">
                                            <h4>Burger Meal</h4>
                                            <h7>£8.99</h7>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>



                                <div class="col-lg-3 item extras mb-3">
                                    <div class="product">
                                        <img src="Images/extras-1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                        <div class="text-center mb-3 mt-3">
                                            <h4>Macaroni Sallad</h4>
                                            <h7>£7.99</h7>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 item maincourse mb-3">
                                    <div class="product ">
                                        <img src="Images/main-meal-6.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                        <div class="text-center mb-3 mt-3">
                                            <h4>Fish & Beans</h4>
                                            <h7>£12.99</h7>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 item extras mb-3">
                                    <div class="product ">
                                        <img src="Images/extras-2.jpg" class="img-fluid img-filter">
                                        <div class="text-center mb-3 mt-3">
                                            <h4>Avacado Sallad</h4>
                                            <h7>£9.99</h7>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 item desserts mb-3">
                                    <div class="product">
                                        <img src="Images/dessert-3.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                        <div class="text-center mb-3 mt-3">
                                            <h4>Chocolate Cake</h4>
                                            <h7>£7.99</h7>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When your grid overflows, run this in the console.

(Code from javascript.js at line 217)

```
 var $projects = $(".projects");
   $projects.isotope({
     itemSelector: ".item",
     layoutMode:'fitRows'

  });
```

I think that this function runs before everything loads.
I don't know what is going on because sometimes this fixes the issue once called but most of the time it does not. But one is for sure. A function defines the absolute position, so the issue lays somewhere within the javascript source.